# Meaning of Drupal 7 access arguments

Tags: drupal-7

```
'access arguments' => array('administer node'),------
```

I came across this line while going through a Drupal 7 program. Can anybody explain regarding what this means?

Comment: Check the following link, mostly related with hook_menu(). https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x  Please do some research on your own before asking questions !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal hook\_menu explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994899/drupal-hook-menu-explaination)